# User cannot see any custom and some system entities only in advanced find in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a weird issue in an organization i have recently taken over, and briefly what it is, is that no users can do advanced find on any custom entities, and on most of the system entities. The entities are simply not there to be selected for advanced find.

Issue was first reported as, no user having permissions to run reports. After which i have thoroughly checked the reporting services permissions, execution service accounts, etc. And all of them seems to be configured fine.

[image: Not Enough privileges to run reports]

After this i have noticed that when i try to do an advanced find, i do not see any of the custom or system entities. In the advanced find, only some system ones. Now, when accessing through the sitemap, these custom and system entities are accessible and you can do things like edits of fields and export to excel. But from advanced find nothing.

[image: Messed up Advanced find]

I have considered this to be a security roles issue, although I have System Admin and System Customizer roles, and the user must not have any permissions on an entity so they don't appear in the advanced find, but still the entities are not in the advanced find. I have also tried exporting all roles from a working organization to the one with the issue. Nothing changes.

Another issue with this is that user cannot do Bulk Deletion, as advanced find queries are used there as well.

Next thing that popped in my mind to check is the CAL user setting. So i disabled all users in the system, and left only mine with access mode READ-WRITE, License Mode Professional. Again, nothing.

Additional Information 1:

I transferred over the problematic organization to a new Server, same thing. This led me thinking that repair would not do much, as it is organization related, and not server related. I have also installed SP1 on the server, which passed fine, but issue remained. There is another organization on the same server, with the same solution/s installed which doesn't have the problem. So it is organization specific.

Does anyone have any suggestions how someone could have messed this up in a potentially unsupported way, as this unsupported is the only thing that comes to mind next?

Comment: strange, do you have access to run a repair?

Comment: I transferred over the organization to a new Server, same thing. This led me thinking that repair would not do much, as it is organization related, and not server related. 

I have also installed SP1 on the server, which passed fine, but issue remained. There is another organization on the same server, with the same solution/s installed which doesn't have the problem. So it is organization specific.

Comment: Have you tried removing all roles from one of the affected users and re-assigning them?

Comment: Have you checked that no one has hacked none of the tables in the metadata schema in the database. As you can hide entities from advanced search by doing this ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Yes Stefan, that is the next thing I've done, and posted what i found in my answer below.  But I have another problem now. Each entity and relationship has two rows in these two tables, Entity and Relationship, and one of them is set to IsValidForAdvancedFind = 1, and the other now. This is from a working organization. How can i know which one to set in the organization with the issue? If i match by GUID they are not all the same, If i match by name i will set both of these rows to true, which might mess up other stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, like almost every time you post a question on Stack Overflow, you suddenly get much more creative and get additional ideas on how to troubleshoot and approach your problem.
Since i checked the customization.xml file for any settings containing '*advancedfind*' and didn't find any there, i tried searching in the database.

I did a sql query searching all columns, for their names, in the CRM organization database and found out the ***IsValidForAdvancedFind*** flag in the Entity and Relationship Metadata Tables.

[image]

For all entities not appearing in Advanced find, this was set to 0, so when you set this flag for an entity and its relationship to '1', the entity appears in the advanced find.

Now, there is an extra problem I encountered here, is that for most of the records in the Entity and Relationship tables, for the same entity, relationship name, there are two rows for some entities and relationships. At the moment this is still under investigation.

***Update/Edit 2***

The extra problem encountered was confirmed that both of the records from an entity or relationship in a the two tables, reflected the same value in the 
***IsValidForAdvancedFind*** flag in both rows for each entity or relationship. The extra row had most probably appeared after the update was installed. So setting the flag to 1 in both rows didn't cause a problem.

Any one that might be looking at this resolution, please make a back up of your database before proceeding with this fix, and do extensive testing before doing it on production.

***End Update/Edit 2***

The **FUN** thing in all this, is that this modification directly in the DB, an **UNSUPPORTED** one, was done by a **Microsoft Partner**. Seems passing certificates to become a partner, doesn't fill in some blanks on how to customize Dynamics. Anyway...

Comment: There is a rule of though that says that if something is in your system and its unsupported and broken. You are going to have to make unsupported changes to fix the problem. With that in mind, I would make a back up of your live environment and restore it for a dev CRM Tenant. Then you have a safe area to trail your fixes

Comment: Exactly, Yes, Stefan. The unsupported fix was in my mind as well. So did some querying in a working organization and a non working organization, matched the two tables by name, and update the flags. I've tested this on a restore from the production one and no issues so far.